# webview E/SelfBrailleClient: Failed to bind to service

Tags: android, webview

**Device information**
Galaxy S4
Android 4.4.2
SCH-I959

**log information**
Use the webview get below error log:

`03-08 13:05:04.998 32665-32665/com.iamcxl.webview E/SelfBrailleClient: Failed to bind to service`

**device screen show blank**

---

**I rotate the screen**

`03-08 13:12:35.113 32665-32665/com.iamcxl.webview E/ActivityThread: Activity com.iamcxl.webview.ActivityWebview0 has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.org.chromium.com.googlecode.eyesfree.braille.selfbraille.SelfBrailleClient$Connection@42c9eb88 that was originally bound here
                                                                    android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Activity com.iamcxl.webview.ActivityWebview0 has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.org.chromium.com.googlecode.eyesfree.braille.selfbraille.SelfBrailleClient$Connection@42c9eb88 that was originally bound here
                                                                        at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:1000)
                                                                        at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:894)
                                                                        at android.app.ContextImpl.bindServiceCommon(ContextImpl.java:1949)
                                                                        at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1932)`